# Why must be 8192 in boost::array<char,8192>?

Tags: boost

if not 8192, the complier tell me error

> error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from
>   'boost::array *' to
>   'boost::array
>   *' C:\boost\boost_1_42\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp 391

HOW to understand 8192?

Comment: 8192 is the size of the array. Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `std::vector` (for one obvious comparison) a `boost::array` has a fixed size, which you have to pass as the second template parameter.